# Remote Message Queue without local Message Queuing server

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, message-queue

Is it possible to use Message Queuing in a .net application without having the Message Queuing server installed on the client machine.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can send messages to a remote server, does that fit your needs?
See: http://www.infosysblogs.com/microsoft/2007/02/msmq_sending_message_to_remote.html

Comment: Based on that you need a local queue server :)

Comment: 6. Finally, when you send messages to remote queue, a temporary outgoing queue is created on your own machine. This is used in case the remote queue is unavailable. If you go to the computer Management console (compmgmt.msc), and expand the Services and Applications / Message Queuing / Outgoing Queues, you would see these queues. The right side of the console should show the details including the state (connected or not) and the IP address(es) for the next hop(s).